# How can I observe the whole body with MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a certain function to be called whenever another script adds a `div` to the `body`.

I tried:

```
var dom_observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutation) {
    console.log('function called');
});
var container = document.body;
console.log(container);
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
dom_observer.observe(container, config);
```

I tried setting `container` to `document.body` (example above) and to `document.querySelector('body')`. In both cases, `console.log()` displayed `null` and I got the following error: `TypeError: Argument 1 of MutationObserver.observe is not an object.`. The callback function was not called when a `div` was added to the `body`.

I tried setting it to `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` and to `document.documentElement.childNodes[1]`. In both cases, `console.log()` displayed`undefined` and the callback function was still never called.

Comment: When are you calling this script ? Is your DOM loaded at that time ? if `console.log(document.body)` outputs `null` it's either that you are not in an HTML document, either that the markup's parsing is only at the `<head>`. Ps : if you're not yet comfortable with DOM parsing and the different load events, delay a little bit your learning of Mutation Observer, chances are great you don't even need it.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution. I had to put the code inside `jQuery(document).ready(function{…});`. Fixed everything. You could post this as the question answer.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that you're setting the target as `document`, and not `container`. To make sure this is cross-browser compatible, use `document.documentElement` along with `document.body`. The following should work:

```
var dom_observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutation) {
    console.log('function called');
});
var container = document.documentElement || document.body;
console.log(container);
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
dom_observer.observe(container, config);
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9xfg2o0L/1/)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would presume it's because this doesn't work - as your fiddle even shows

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The fiddle does indeed work. See the console when using `document` instead of `container`. I even tested it by adding something to the body afterwards.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I was confused as your fiddle did not call the function as you don't make any amendments to the DOM.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated the fiddle to add an element to the DOM.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake copy-pasting my code to StackOverflow. I actually tried this code already, but `console.log` displayed `null` and I got the following error: `TypeError: Argument 1 of MutationObserver.observe is not an object`. I think this is because Firefox doesn't support `document.body`.

Comment: @Louis-MarieMatthews See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, the problem actually came from the fact my script was called even though the DOM was not completely loaded. Putting the code inside `jQuery(document).ready(function{…});` solved everything. However I was wrong, Firefox supports `document.body`. Using your updated code actually prevents the script from working.

Comment: Oh, alright then.

Comment: `document` is a valid node for `MutationObserver.observe()`. The OP's problem was that they weren't using `subtree:true` in the observer.